# Enhancing Pre-Learned Model with Human Input to better determine image similarity using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision

Suppose I would like to build a tool that would tell me on a scale from 0 to 1 the similarity between images.

[image]

I could go ahead and download a pre-trained mage models such as vgg16, remove its last layers (classifier), convert the images into feature vectors using the pre-trained model and finally compute the similarity between the vectors using something like the cosine similarity.

[image]

The method is better explained here: https://mc.ai/find-more-like-this-product-using-transfer-learning/

**... but what if I wanted to enhance the tool using my own dataset ?**
More specifically, I have a dataset where humans either said that two pictures where similar (1) or not similar (0):

[image]

**I was wondering, if you see a way how I could in-cooperate this to enhance the similarity score tool ?**
 Many thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a siamese network with a VGG-16 base. The model will be trained with your labeled images, similar images will be trained with a similarity of 1, different images will be trained with the similarity of 0.

Triplet loss can be used to minimize the dissimilarity between the same objects.

Here is an implementation in keras: https://medium.com/@prabhnoor0212/siamese-network-keras-31a3a8f37d04

Training process with your dataset:

Let's say you have a simple classification dataset. So, you have a class for apples, one for cats, and so on.

1. First, you'll want to make sure the images in a single class are very similar.

(If you put a car and a truck in the same class and expect them to have a similarity score of 1, it'll make your network perform poorly)

2. Once you have the dataset, you'll just need to generate pairs, if two images are from same class the label will be 1. and if not the label will be 0.
3. Now, just train the model with triplet loss and VGG siamese.

You can modify the code examples, and even find many resources which shares code.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I am quite new to this, so please bear with me, if this is evident... I read the web-page on siamese network that you link but I don't see how to train it with my dataset? Do you have any example or reference ?

Comment: The training process is the same for any other siamese network, read the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the update! Will the output still be a number between 0 and 1 or will it just be 0 or 1 ? I would want the tool to output something between 0 and 1 to have a feeling for the tool´s certainty about the similarity.

Comment: Yes, you can use a soft label without any doubt, for example, a cat and a cheetah may have a similarity 0.23, but it's a tiring process, so usually 0 and 1 are chosen for simplicity.

Comment: Great ! Thank you very much for your help and suggestion !

Comment: Actually, why triple loss, if we compare two images? I don't understand number 3. Thanks for your help.